# ASP.NET MVC5 - DropDownList with Active Directory Users

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I got stuck when I try to post Users from Active Directory to my SQL Database.

This is what I got so far:

ViewModel:

```
 public class UserViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myADUsers { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserViewModel myADUsers = new UserViewModel();           
        myADUsers.myADUsers = GetADUsers();

        return View(myADUsers);

    }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetADUsers()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> _users = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //Instantiate Active Directory Server Connection
        PrincipalContext adServer = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);

        //Instantiate Active Directory User Group
        GroupPrincipal adGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adServer, "XXXXX");

        if (adGroup != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal p in adGroup.GetMembers())
            {
                _users.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = p.SamAccountName, Value = p.SamAccountName });
            }
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myADUsers = _users;

        return myADUsers;
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("My AD Users", Model.myADUsers, "Please select a user")
```

This works fine, as my DropDownList is populated with my Users from Active Directory but how do I get the selected User?

I'd be very grateful to get some tipps.. Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to send the name of the user to your controller method?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Yeah, I want to send the selected Username back to the Controller where I want to fill my UserName Property of my Database Model (EF6).

Comment: glad, it helped you

Comment: @exmachina is there something else to the dropdownlist that wasn't given in the code above? I tried using that same code in my MVC5 app and all I get is an error saying `HtmlHelper has no applicable method named DropDownList but appears to have an extension method by that name.` I don't need a dropdown list, I just wanted an example for the AD search I am trying to build into an autocompleting textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that `DropDownList` into the `Html.BeginForm`as I did this below:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {

    @Html.DropDownList("users", Model.myADUsers, "Please select a user")
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
```

And then receive the user's name in your method like this:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(string users)
{ 
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: @exmachina  
Please accept an answer to show others it was helpful and that was answered